# How to set the language for the user interface using vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I know I can change the language of the Vim user interface using `:language en_US.UTF-8`, but how can I do that using vimscript?

`set language=en_US.UTF-8` is invalid, and the Vim documentation says that the `v:lang` variable cannot be set directly.

Comment: `:language` *is* Vimscript... Do you mean change it to a value that's in a variable? You can use `:execute` for that, like `:execute "language" mylang` where the `mylang` variable has `en_US.UTF-8` or suchlike.

Comment: `:language` is a command, not a setting. Did you try simply `language en_US.UTF-8` (without `set` and without `=`)?